# How can i send messages to all my slack users

Tags: notifications, webhooks, slack, slack-api

I am developing a slack application and I will publish this application on the app directory. I want anyone who downloads my app to be able to read the messages I send. However, a new webhook url is created for each user who installs my application on his own workspace. What I want is to send messages to all users via a single webhook. Is this possible or not possible how can I easily do what I want.

I'm looking forward to your messages and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to send a DM to every user of your application in a single call, either via the Webhook or the Web API.

The only possible way is to iterate over your entire user list and use `chat.postMessage`, but I'd advise against that as you may hit rate limits and/or be perceived as spammy.